# Display an icon for each number of bedrooms (property website) php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a property website.

At the moment, on the listing, and in search results, it says Number of bedrooms: [pulls the number from the database]. It uses an array variable, $a1[rooms].

Instead, I want to display a small icon of a bed for the number of bedrooms. So if three bedrooms then it should say, Number of bedrooms: [bed img] [bed img] [bed img]. [bed img] of course being a small icon/image of a bed.

So whether there are 1 bedrooms or 5 bedrooms, this is the number of times I want the icon displayed. The number of bedrooms is stored here: $a1[rooms].

Fairly simple really.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
for ($bed_counter = 1; $bed_counter <= $a1['rooms']; $bed_counter++) {
   print '<img src="bed.jpg">';
}
```

Comment: glad to help! please check this answer as accepted :)